# How to read character from array's elements

Tags: java, arrays, character

My array is `Object[] Words;`

There are

```
Words[0]=Apple-Alim,AlimniiMod; 
Words[1]=Anxious-SanaaZowson,SetgelTugshse; 
Words[2]=Car-Mashin,MashinTereg,Wagon etc..
```

How I read characters until `'-'`

Comment: why type object? why not type string?

Comment: I agree.  Why not use `String`?  You can use `indexOf` to find the index of the `-`, then use `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to `String[]` array and try playing with it ,

```
String[] wordArray= Arrays.copyOf(Words, Words.length, String[].class);
```

use `indexOf()` method to find the occurance of `-` char . extract the rest using `subString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object[] words = new Object[5];

    words[0] = new String("Apple-Alimnii, jskdhj");

    for(int i = 0; i < ((String)words[0]).length(); i++) {

        System.out.print(((String)words[0]).charAt(i));

        if(((String)words[0]).charAt(i) == '-')
            break;
    }
}
```